# "unable to connect" to .py script on lighttpd webserver, raspberry pi running archlinux

Tags: python, cgi, raspberry-pi, lighttpd, archlinux

I'm trying to setup a lighttpd webserver on my raspberry pi running archlinux.

I followed the guide on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lighttpd

I get a fine html test page on localhost, but I can't run a .py script.
I've never set up a webserver before, so I might have done something trivial wrong.

I'm not sure where to put my script. I tried both /srv/http/index.py and /srv/http/index.py
I get

"Unable to connect"

I hope someone can help me out.

My /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf is as follows, and my  /etc/lighttp/conf.d/cgi-conf is pasted in below.

```
# This is a minimal example config
# See /usr/share/doc/lighttpd
# and http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOpti$

include "conf.d/cgi.conf"

server.port             = 80
server.username         = "http"
server.groupname        = "http"
server.document-root    = "/srv/http"
server.errorlog         = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
dir-listing.activate    = "enable"
index-file.names        = ( "index.html" )
mimetype.assign         = (
                            ".html" => "text/html",
                            ".txt" => "text/plain",
                            ".css" => "text/css",
                            ".js" => "application/x-javascript",
                            ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
                            ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
                            ".gif" => "image/gif",
                            ".png" => "image/png",
                            "" => "application/octet-stream"
                    )


#server.modules = (
"mod_access",
"mod_alias",    
"mod_compress",
"mod_redirect",
"mod_cgi",
"mod_rewrite",
)


$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
cgi.assign = (".py" => "/usr/bin/python")
}
```

cgi.conf:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

cgi.assign                 = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
                           ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl",
                           ".rb"  => "/usr/bin/ruby",
                           ".erb" => "/usr/bin/eruby",
                           ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python2",
                           ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )

index-file.names           += ( "index.pl",   "default.pl",
                           "index.rb",   "default.rb",
                           "index.erb",  "default.erb",
                           "index.py",   "default.py",
                           "index.php",  "default.php" )
```

Comment: Firstly, the two locations you say you've tried are the same. Secondly, you don't say what address you went to to run your script.

Comment: sorry the other address were /srv/http/cgi-bin, I open 192.168.0.105/index.py. One 192.168.0.105 I get my html testpage